# How can I automatically HREF the articles of my MongoDB database to each article specific page?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working on a site which is more of a DB project that anything else. Currently I mainly using my mongoDB database to show the previews of those articles after querying them with these functions (which are in 2 different files)

```php
//this one is from the functions file which i load in all the various pages of the site
function article_recordset() {
   

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$i = 0;
$SiteArticles = $client->SiteArticles;
$articoli=$SiteArticles->Articles;
$cursor = $articoli->find();
return $cursor;

    foreach ($cursor as $articolo) {      
        $recordset = array(
            $i=$i+1 => array(
                "title" => $articolo["title"],
                "description" => $articolo["content"],
                "article" => "",
            )
        );
    }

}
```

```php
//this is the index.php file so the homepage where i display the articles which i stored into an array and then i display with an echo later

include("funzioni.inc.php");//name of the functions file

$ARR_articles = article_recordset();

$STR_article = NULL;

foreach($ARR_articles as $index => $article){
    $STR_article .= get_article_item_html(
        $img_path = "img/article/".$index.".jpg", 
        $title = $article["title"], 
        $description = $article["content"]
    );
}
```

The display works fine and all but what I'm trying to do is to HREF each displayed article preview to their own article page

So article 1 is displayed and is linked to the page of `localhost/folder/article1.php` for example

Now the href I want to do is somewhat automatic so it links to each article page which I manually created already just like it does the foreach for the query of all the article contents

So like it's going to store each article in the array which I display later while also like setting an href to each one

For example:

Query article 1, store into array, display that array content for article 1 and href it to it's own page, and so on for each article

Note: I want to ""automate"" just the HREF of each queried article not automate the article page creation since I have those pages already created and it's for a small project and nothing too serious

Comment: Maybe you should use `GET` in link? `localhost/folder/article.php?id=1`? Then to know what page is being requested use `$_GET['id']`.. I think that's what your asking at least.

Comment: i don't realy get the use the GET in the link cause basically what i do with the DB is show some previews of the articles that are currently stored in the DB but i want to link those displayed previews to the actual article pages and idk how the get link would work for it